Vertex move not affecting all faces
I created an object, duplicated and mirrored it and joined the 2 together to create a symetrical solid shape.
All fine but if I select one of the vertices on the joined seam and move it, only the faces on one side are affected. It doesn't affect the faces on the other side, suggesting the 2 sides are not actually joined.
If I drag select over the vertex, it suggests there is only 1 vertex, not 2. However, if I move the vertex, I now see a vertex for the other side where the single vertex used to be and if I select both these vertices I can Merge At First to properly join them back in the correct position but I surely shouldn't have to do that for all 50 vertices along the seam.
Drag selecting each vertex in turn and choosing Merge At Center doesn't work, as if it didn't find 2 vertices.
What step have I missed when joining the 2 halves that means that the seam vertices are noted as single vertices but aren't actually connected to all faces? And what is the simplest way to get these vertices to act correctly?
Face orientation is correct.


Hello, I'm not sure to understand but if you select everything and M > Merge by Distance, does it not give what you want?

Hi Moonboots. No Merge operation fixes this if the vertices on each side are shown as a single vertex (like the ones above and below the 'hole' in the image). If I move one, like in the image, I open up a hole and you can see the original vertex and the moved one. Selecting those and using Merge joins them perfectly. I just can't merge the vertices without moving every single vertex first which seems longwinded.

I've realised that if I go into xray view I can select both vertices and Merge, so it's the solid view hiding the other vertex that stops the merge. The bigger question is how to join 2 objects so these vertices automatically fuse into a single vertex. Thanks.

when you model a symmetrical object, the best is to use the Mirror modifier, but you can also symmetrize with the Mesh > Symmetrize operation in Edit mode, then choose the axis in the Operator Box, note that the location of the origin will be used as symmetry center
